# Can't bake Vertex Animation to object when export as fbx

Tags: .fbx

first of all I'm a newbie in blender
I found a useful python code on the internet that imports an animated object(grasshopper kangaroo cloth simulation  ) from csv files(every row represent vertex position of a mesh)
it updates the position of each mesh vertex in each keyframe so I can play the animation in blender environment
the question is how to export the animated object to FBX file format so as to use it in renderer such as Lumion or d5 render

the blender file is [Here](https://easyupload.io/nl6m1e)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build-in FBX-Importer-Exporter plugin **does not** yet support shape-key/vertex animations.

There is a paid third party plugin called Better FBX Importer Exporter. This does support vertex animations.
https://blendermarket.com/products/better-fbx-importer--exporter

However, I would recommend using alembic as export, because this does bake any vertex animations into the format. Given you don't want to purchase the plugin and your destination software supports alembic.

Source: Have a look here under "Missing"
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html